# Ruby different behavior depend of block type

Tags: ruby, block

Good day.
I have different behavior of the same chunk of code depends on type of block syntax curly braces or do/end. The block with do/end just skipped without any error notification:

Block with curly brackets just implements and `p` prints `one Ruby is a COOL language!`:

```
p "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) {
   "one " + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
}
```

The 'same' snippet of code in with do/end just skipped, and `p` show me `Enumerator` `<Enumerator: "rubyisacoollanguage":gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/)>`:

```
p "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) do
    "two " + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
end
```

I think it happens because of `p` in second case it's eliminates block. Things become clear when I add `p` inside blocks. Data from first block print 2 times, when data from second did not prited at all.

```
p "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) {
   p "one " + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
}
p "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) do
    p "two " + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
end
```

It was quite strange and unpredictable behavior for me. No error, just skip part of the code. Why it's happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it happen?

Because {} and do/end have different precedence. {} is "stronger". As in "is associated to the nearest method call". So this

```
p foo {
  something
}
```

Is seen like this.

```
p (foo {
  something
})
```

And do/end is like this

```
p(foo) do
  something
end
```

> No error, just skip part of the code

Yes, due to another feature of ruby. Which is "you can pass a block to ANY method. It is then that method's responsibility to use or ignore it." Here `p` does not expect a block and simply ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Ruby's loose syntax rules is that sometimes it gets tripped up on who the block belongs to. Due to ambiguity both `p` and `gsub` could "own" that block. The `do` method gets assigned to `p`, while the `{ ... }` approach gets pinned on `gsub`.

This is probably due to some operator precedence type rule though as the block is not an operator per-se, I'm not sure I can find a reference for that particular behaviour right now.

Where there's ambiguity it's best to avoid depending on how it gets interpreted and instead be more specific:

```
rv = "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) do
  "two" + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
end

p rv
```

Here `rv =` can't take a block so it doesn't end up grabbing it inadvertently.

You can also do this:

```
p(
  "rubyisacoollanguage".gsub(/(ruby)(is)(a)(cool)(language)/) do
    "two" + $1.capitalize + " %s %s %s %s!" % [$2,$3,$4.upcase,$5]
  end
)
```

Where you're making it abundantly clear who gets what.

Comment: Yeah, resorting to assignment is sometimes just unnecessary hoop to jump through, when I'm decorating the code with debug printing. So are parentheses :/